# asp.net, multiple sites, multiple versions - which source control?

Tags: git, svn, controls

I recently started work at a new company which has have 4 live versions of the same site with slight differences. We have no source control and no development environment. The current development team consists of one person. Me.

I need to implement some source control that houses both the current live environment and a new development one. I also need a copy of the code on a remote location to protect it should anything happen to my hardware or the dev env.

As you can appreciate, the current live environment has a different config and lives in a different location to the development.

My question: Should I use Git, SVN or some other software?
Is it possible to have a GIT branch point to a different file location?

At the moment I am using bitbucket and sourcetree. I have managed to 'track' the updates from one repo to the remote. But I am stuggling to setup the dev side. It seems that each branch lives locally inside the original repo.

If not, would it be better to have a current live repo and a seperate dev?
Then merge upon a release? I think I may have just answered my own question. But, as this is the foundations for all future developments I know it is important to get this part correct. Fortunately/unfortunately this side of software development has normally been established prior. Any suggestions will be greatly received. Thank you.

Comment: I would probably leans towards using Git, unless most of the files you are versioning are binaries, in which case I might choose something else.  By the way, your question is very broad and will invite opinions (like this one).

Comment: Thank you. Broad? I totally agree. I'm under quite a bit of pressure to get this done and I genuinely don't know enough about it. I asked a similar question and got marked down. The team consists of me at the moment and I'm not terribly comfortable with this. I guess I just need someone to say - you're heading down the right path but try this. Thank you :)

Comment: I think Git would be good for your situation because it is open source, free, and will make your code portable.  There is a bit of a learning curve, but it is smooth sailing on the other side if you make it.

Comment: So... I've done some research. I think it looks like 2 seperate repo's - one live and one dev. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Question : Repo A and Repo B - Merge A into B as a submerge.... If I was to modify the code on A at a later date, will that automatically appear in the sub branch of B? Or, is it like a snapshot?

Comment: To use your language, it will be like a snapshot.  Modifying one branch in Git does not and should not affect another branch directly.